# How do I open a local file from a button press in JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JavaScript and HTML.
I created an example where im trying to open a local file called, "TNTplayer.html" in a JavaScript function via a button press. However, I don't know the line of code that will do that.

```js
function myFunction() {
document.location.href=document.location.href.splitOnLast('/')[0]+"/TNTplayer.html";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button.</p>
    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You can't really do that. If you mean "link there", all you need is `document.location.href="TNTplayer.html";`, provided your current HTML file is also local and the other file is in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article: http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/open-a-local-file-with-javascript.html

In general, if your HTML/JS is being served as a website, you will not have "true" access to your filesystem (which is a necessary security measure), besides the ways mentioned in the article above.

However, if you are serving it as a standalone client application, which is possible using frameworks such as Nodejs and others, there are framework specific ways of accessing the filesystem.